Obtain LLVM IR after linking with C++ STD library?
I am trying to analyse instruction count of a C++ program using LLVM passes. Issue is the when i use function from standard library like sqrt() from cmath, the LLVM IR does not contain the instructions from sqrt() but instead represents it like
declare double @sqrt(double noundef) #1

This is causing problems from me as I am unable to count the total number of instruction in entire program. Below is my C++ Program
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num = 10;
    float c = (float) std::sqrt((double) num);
    return 0;
}

and the LLVM IR
; ModuleID = 'hello.cpp'
source_filename = "hello.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-i128:128-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

module asm ".globl _ZSt21ios_base_library_initv"

; Function Attrs: mustprogress noinline norecurse nounwind uwtable
define dso_local noundef i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca float, align 4
  store i32 0, ptr %1, align 4
  store i32 10, ptr %2, align 4
  %4 = load i32, ptr %2, align 4
  %5 = sitofp i32 %4 to double
  %6 = call double @sqrt(double noundef %5) #2
  %7 = fptrunc double %6 to float
  store float %7, ptr %3, align 4
  ret i32 0
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare double @sqrt(double noundef) #1

attributes #0 = { mustprogress noinline norecurse nounwind uwtable "frame-pointer"="all" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cmov,+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
attributes #1 = { nounwind "frame-pointer"="all" "no-trapping-math"="true" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cmov,+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "tune-cpu"="generic" }
attributes #2 = { nounwind }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0, !1, !2, !3, !4}
!llvm.ident = !{!5}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!1 = !{i32 8, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!2 = !{i32 7, !"PIE Level", i32 2}
!3 = !{i32 7, !"uwtable", i32 2}
!4 = !{i32 7, !"frame-pointer", i32 2}
!5 = !{!"Ubuntu clang version 18.1.3 (1)"}



The example function sqrt will already be in machine code in a library provided by your compiler vendor you would need to compile the standard library for your system from source to see it's IR.  Other code eg std::vector is header only code and you should be able to get the IR.

Actually that is the problem. i want the IR representation of sqrt if possible. I am performing software to hardware mapping. i have to know what is going on inside sqrt

Then you need the source code for your standard library,

If you target at least AVX instructions, the standard library might well use a bit of hand-written assembly language optimization, so sqrt will end up as mostly a vsqrtsd instruction.

I cant make the code hardware dependant. I am loosking for a more hardware agnostic approach. I am just not sure how i could integrate the c++ std library functions with my llvm.

A C++ Standard Library implementation is always hardware dependent.  That's one of it's jobs to be the abstraction layer between the hardware/OS and Standard C++.

Note also that functions in the Standard Library are not required to even exist.  They can be implemented directly by "compiler magic". Or there might be an implementation but the compiler is not required to use it in all cases.
